# Assigning value to id gives error add_to_fav() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

This code below include my datatable and up to my error line. I could not find any solution or similar code to fix mine. Any help would be very appreciated. Simple explation is highly needed since I'm very new to coding. Thank you so much.

```
def create_datatable(self):
    self.data_table = MDDataTable(
        size_hint = (1, 1),
        use_pagination = True,
        background_color = app.theme_cls.bg_normal,
        column_data = [
            ('Id', dp(10)),
            ('Name', dp(35)),
            ('CAS', dp(25)),
            ('Molecular Weight', dp(30)),
            ('Category', dp(25)),
            ('Boiling Point', dp(25)),
            ('Melting Point', dp(25)),
            ('Saved', dp(25))
        ],
        row_data = [],
        elevation = 1
    )
    self.data_table.bind(on_row_press=self.on_row_press)
    self.manager.get_screen('mainscreen').ids['datatable'].add_widget(self.data_table)

def on_row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row):
    self.row_num = int(instance_row.index/len(instance_table.column_data))
    self.row_data = instance_table.row_data[self.row_num]
    print(self.row_data[0])
    self.description = self.row_data[1]
    self.cas = self.row_data[2]
    self.mw = self.row_data[3]
    self.category = self.row_data[4]
    self.boil = self.row_data[5]
    self.melt = self.row_data[6]
    self.saved = self.row_data[7]

    self.show_info_dialog()


def show_info_dialog(self):
    print('table popup')
    if not self.dialog:
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            title = 'Chemical information',
            type = 'confirmation',
            items = [
                RowPopup(id = 'chemname', text = f"Name: {self.description}"),
                RowPopup(id = 'cas', text = f"Cas Nunber: {self.cas}"),
                RowPopup(text = f"Molecular Weight: {self.mw}"),
                RowPopup(text = f"Catergory: {self.category}"),
                RowPopup(text = f"Boiling Point: {self.boil}"),
                RowPopup(text = f"Melting Point: {self.melt}"),
            ],
            buttons = [
                MDFlatButton(
                    text = 'CANCEL',
                    theme_text_color = 'Custom',
                    text_color = app.theme_cls.text_color,
                    on_release = self.cancel_dialog
                ),
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text='ADD TO FAVORITE',
                    theme_text_color = 'Custom',
                    md_bg_color = app.theme_cls.primary_color,
                    elevation = 0,
                    on_release = self.add_to_fav
                )
            ]
        )
    self.dialog.open()

def cancel_dialog(self, inst):
    self.dialog.dismiss()
    self.dialog = None

def add_to_fav(self):
    print('add to favorite')
    saved = '1'
    id = self.row_num[0]
    print(id)
    self.database.update_chemical(id, saved)
    self.reload_data_table()
    self.dialog.dismiss()
    self.dialog = None
```

I'm changing the saved value to 1, so it would show up in another table with the condition saved == 1, and I'm stucked at changing it when the 'add to favorite' event is happening. Another error that I also met when fixing this is int is not subscriptable.

Comment: I've never used Kivy, but it seems like `on_release` functions are given a value. Your function doesn't take a value though (besides `self`), thus the error. Either give your `add_to_fav` a second parameter, or change the `on_release` line to something like `on_release=lambda _: self.add_to_fav()`

Comment: Is this your full code?  All of these functions take `self` as the first argument, which is normal if they are members of a class, but I don't see a class here.